# what does Curl's stand-alone hyphen (-) mean?

Tags: command-line, curl, parameter

what's the stand-alone hyphen (between the `-C` & `-O`) stand for in this command?

```
curl -C - -O http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/fn67/fn6742.pdf
```

FWIW- I'm following a tutorial [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2011/07/18/attachment-type-in-action.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-C -` automatically determines how to resume the transfer, based upon the input and output files.

From [`man curl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) (note the second paragraph):

```
   -C/--continue-at <offset>
          Continue/Resume a previous file transfer at the  given  offset.
          The  given  offset  is  the  exact number of bytes that will be
          skipped, counting from the beginning of the source file  before
          it  is  transferred  to the destination.  If used with uploads,
          the FTP server command SIZE will not be used by curl.

          Use "-C -" to tell curl to automatically find out where/how  to
          resume  the transfer. It then uses the given output/input files
          to figure that out.

          If this option is used several times,  the  last  one  will  be
          used.
```

Comment: thx. i must have overlooked that in the man page...

Comment: Just a note that for other flags such as -D, -K, -d, etc., curl interpets - as stdin like many unix tools

Answer (score 3):

It will just resume the download from the last position, from [man curl](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=curl&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en):

```
   -C/--continue-at <offset>
          Continue/Resume a previous file transfer at  the  given  offset.
          The  given  offset  is  the  exact  number of bytes that will be
          skipped, counting from the beginning of the source  file  before
          it is transferred to the destination.  If used with uploads, the
          FTP server command SIZE will not be used by curl.

          Use "-C -" to tell curl to automatically find out  where/how  to
          resume  the  transfer. It then uses the given output/input files
          to figure that out.
```